# How to find data from nested array in Mongoose?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern

I have two ids: publisherID and BookID.

My mongoose database looks like:[image]

Now the question is: I want to find **userId** where the publishderId is **59l55llopd3W1FuosGgN** and the bookId is **G1Vfe2NwS3sy-qhT1J0g6**

I've created the following function which returns the null data.

```
const allTheRelatedData = (publiserId, bookId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            myBookSchema
                .findOne({
                    publisherId: publisherId,
                    "books.$.bookId": bookId,
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};
```

When I run this code, it gives null data. Please help, I tried many solutions such as positional, match, etc. Nothing is working. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$ projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) to do that:

```
myBookSchema
  .findOne({
    publisherId: publisherId,
    "books.bookId": bookId,
  }, {
    "books.$": 1
  }
).then((data) => {...
```

Then you can get `userId` with `data.books[0].userId` and remember to check if data or book exists with `if (data && data.books && data.books.length)...`

Comment: Can you please tell what is 1 in the line: books.$: 1? As I don't know the index of the book.

Comment: It will select the first book that match `"books.bookId": bookId` in the condition. You can find more info in the link I provided

Comment: Sorry, but this code:  .findOne(
     {
      publisherId: publisherId,
      "books.bookId": bookId,
     },

     { "books.$": 1 }
    ) is also not working.

Comment: And when I replaced 1 with 0 it gave me error: MongoError: positional projection cannot be used with exclusion

Comment: And `"books.$": 1` is for projection, not for condition.

Comment: When I tried books.$: 1 it is still giving null data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234305/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-agent-k).

Comment: Thank you so much Cuong, for your time and valuable answer. Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: what if one more level nesting?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work

```js
const allTheRelatedData = (publiserId, bookId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            myBookSchema
                .find()
                .then((data) => {
                    const item = data.filter(i => i.publisherId === publisherId && i.books.includes(book => book.bookId === bookId))
                    if (item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        resolve(item);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Not found");
                        reject("Not found");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This one is not working @im2rando also getting a message data.filter is not a function.